Visual Studio 2012 Extension for Matching Curly Braces
I'm looking for a Visual Studio 2012 extension that helps match curly braces ({}) in my code. Ideally, the extension should:

Highlight matching braces when the cursor is on one
Provide navigation shortcuts to jump between matching braces
Support languages like C#, C++, and JavaScript

Does anyone know of a reliable and compatible extension that provides this functionality?enter image description here

Visual Studio highlights matching brackets out of the box for languages like C++, C# and JavaScript when installed, though it's not always very visible. The matching bracket is highlighted when placing the cursor before the opening bracket or after the closing one. Shortcut Ctrl + } can be used to navigate to the matching bracket.
Recommended to use the latest Visual Studio edition, since version 2012 is pretty outdated.
